# When we are using .net core 3.1, How to do a dotnet publish properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

here I want to ask about how we do dotnet publish when you are using .net core 3.1

I have try this :

```
dotnet build project.sln /nologo /p:configuration="release" .....
```

And this :

```
dotnet publish project.sln /nologo /p:configuration="release" ....
```

I found that way in another question of stackoverflow, but it give me error. Hope there are someone help me to resolve this. Thankyou

Comment: What is the error?  I don't understand what your last sentence ("I just want to make it publish using parameter like configuration...") means, but the configuration should be specified as `dotnet build project.sln /nologo --configuration release`.  I think you might have gotten `/p:configuration="release"` from `MSBuild.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following command to publish your dotnet core solution

```
dotnet publish Your_Solution.sln -c Release -o "OUTPUT_DIR_PATH"
```

Execute this command in the root dir of your solution.

For complete list of available parameters of `dotnet publish` command visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21)

Comment: Ah thanks, what is OUTPUT_DIR_PATH  mean ? Is it define where our zip file want to be placed ?

Comment: Yes, but it will not zip. "OUTPUT_DIR_PATH " is the path where you want your published files. You have to zip it yourself.